# $X$ be a random variable with PDF $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$, where $-\infty <x<\infty$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable with PDF $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$, where $-\infty <x<\infty$. Let us define $Y=g(X)$, where $g(x)=1$ if $x>0$, $g(0)=1/2$ and $g(x)=-1$ if $x<0$. Then find out the PDF of $Y$.

I had find the distribution function (DF) of $Y=g(X)$. It looks like this,

$F_Y(y)=$ $P\{Y\leq y\}=0$, if $y<-1$, $=1/2$ if $-1\leq y <1$ and $=1$ otherwise. And from this I want to calculate the PDF of Y. Any help/hint/solution will be very helpful for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks wrong. I think $$
\mathbb P\{Y\le y\}=\begin{cases} 0, & \text{ if }\quad y<-1,\\\frac{1}{2},&\text{ if }\quad y\in[-1,+1),\\ 1,&\text{ if }\quad y\ge +1\,.\end{cases}
$$

Comment: @KurtG. You are exactly correct. I don't know how I found that DF of $Y$. :'(

Comment: @KurtG. Sir can you please help to find out the Density function of $Y$?

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is no PDF because the CDF is not differentiable. In the distributional sense the "density" consists of two Dirac measures each with mass $1/2$ in $-1$ resp. $+1.$

Comment: $Y$ takes only three values as pointed out by @KurtG, it’s a discrete random variable.